# Login to Windows xp programmatically

Tags: c#, logging, windows-xp, network-programming

Anyone heard that it's possible to login to Windows xp programmatically,
I want to modify the way the Domain Controller authenticates the user and if the user authenticated in my special way it returns the user name and password to the service working on the client machine so it should login the user using its passed credentials from the DC without waiting for user to insert his original credentials.

Comment: This kind of stuff worries me. Pass credentials to local service?

Comment: Really I didn't implement it yet but I hope it will work, something about design modification may be done because of using Gina.dll, anyway Thanks too much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at this: [Gina.dll MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375457(VS.85).aspx)

Gina is the system that fingerprint readers etc. use to customise the login screen.  You may be able to use this to achieve your purpose?

To future proof your app (Vista and Windows 7) you may wish to look into these: [MSDN Mag Vista Credential Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx)

Comment: Cheers, I had always wondered how the hell windows allowed a fingerprint to substitute for a 3 finger salute so I looked it up one day... ;)

Comment: Thanks Man, I exactly want to login using fingerprint.