# Windows Vista/7 Programmatically login

Tags: windows-vista, authentication

Is it possible to create a service or application which can programmatically log a user in when windows(vista/win7) starts up.... if a user has a token eg biometrics or smartcard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, it's possible. In older (XP and before) windows, this facility was called a [GINA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375457(VS.85).aspx).  In Vista and Win 7, the architecture is changed... you need to build a [Credential Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx).  The previous link is to an overview article, here's a link to some [samples](http://blogs.msdn.com/karinm/archive/2006/12/30/new-windows-vista-credential-provider-samples.aspx).

Kudos to [Login to windows xp programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464580/login-to-windows-xp-programatically) for providing most of the answers here! ;-)