# Read specific part of the output c#

Tags: c#, cmd

I am creating a UI for our IT Department that shadow a user's session. First, you have to get the session ID using the following command.

```
Process Process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("CMD.exe", "/K" + "qwinsta /server:" + ComputerName + " " + Username);
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

Process = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

And this is what you get out.

|SESSIONNAME|USERNAME|ID |STATE |TYPE|DEVICE|
|-----------|--------|---|------|----|------|
|console    |mlynch  |8  |Active|    |      |
As of right now, this opens the command prompt for this command with the computer name and username you put into a couple of text boxes. You then take the session ID and input it into a 3rd text box and click the connect button. I am trying to bypass this step. Input the computer and username, click connect and it goes. I need to find a way to get the session ID and save it to a string, then reference that string in the next line of code.

```
if (MouseControlCheck.Checked == true)
{
Process Process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("CMD.exe", "/C" + "mstsc.exe /shadow:" + SessionID + " /v " + ComputerName + " /control");
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

Process = Process.Start(startInfo);
}
else
{
Process Process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("CMD.exe", "/C" + "mstsc.exe /shadow:" + SessionID + " /v " + ComputerName);
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

Process = Process.Start(startInfo);
}
```

How do I read the session ID to a string?

TLDR: I want to skip over console and mlynch and just get to the number under ID. This is not going to be used to get the local machine ID, I want the ID of a computer on the network.

Comment: Found my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59274974/find-specific-text-in-richtextbox-and-set-it-to-a-string-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I had to do.

```
Process GetSessionID = new Process();
GetSessionID.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";
GetSessionID.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C" + "for /f \"skip=1 tokens=3\" %1 in ('query user " + Username + "/server:" + ComputerName + "') do @echo %1";
GetSessionID.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
GetSessionID.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
GetSessionID.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
GetSessionID.Start();
SessionIDOutput = GetSessionID.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
GetSessionID.WaitForExit();
DoAllTheThingsTextBox.Text = SessionIDOutput;
if (GetSessionID.HasExited == true)
{
    var digitArray = DoAllTheThingsTextBox.Text.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray();
    SessionID = new String(digitArray);

    if (MouseControlCheck.Checked == true)
    {
        Process Process = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("CMD.exe", "/C" + "mstsc /shadow:" + SessionID + " /v " + ComputerName + " /control");
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        Process = Process.Start(startInfo);
    }
    else
    {
        Process Process = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("CMD.exe", "/C" + "mstsc /shadow:" + SessionID + " /v " + ComputerName);
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        Process = Process.Start(startInfo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [MS site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput?view=netframework-4.8)

You need to add RedirectStandardOutput = true and then Read Standardoutput.

```
string[] allLines;
using (Process process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "ipconfig.exe";
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.Start();

            // Synchronously read the standard output of the spawned process. 
            StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput;
            string output = reader.ReadToEnd();

            // Convert all text to string array
            allLines = output.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            // Write the redirected output to this application's window.
            Console.WriteLine(output);

            process.WaitForExit();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this post, [c# how to determine session id of specific logged in windows user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39751133/c-sharp-how-to-determine-session-id-of-specific-logged-in-windows-user), might be easier to just use windows api to get the user session info. This removes the need to call cmd and parse the output. I modified it slightly to get a specific user

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // this code gets the users from localhost -
        // can change this to a remote hostname on the network
        Console.Write(UserLogins.GetUser("COMPUTER_NAME", "USER_NAME"));

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    public class UserLogins
    {

        [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr WTSOpenServer([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String pServerName);

        [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
        static extern void WTSCloseServer(IntPtr hServer);

        [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
        static extern Int32 WTSEnumerateSessions(
            IntPtr hServer,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] Int32 Reserved,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] Int32 Version,
            ref IntPtr ppSessionInfo,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] ref Int32 pCount);

        [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
        static extern void WTSFreeMemory(IntPtr pMemory);

        [DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll")]
        static extern bool WTSQuerySessionInformation(
            System.IntPtr hServer, int sessionId, WTS_INFO_CLASS wtsInfoClass, out System.IntPtr ppBuffer, out uint pBytesReturned);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct WTS_SESSION_INFO
        {
            public Int32 SessionID;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public String pWinStationName;

            public WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS State;
        }

        public enum WTS_INFO_CLASS
        {
            WTSInitialProgram,
            WTSApplicationName,
            WTSWorkingDirectory,
            WTSOEMId,
            WTSSessionId,
            WTSUserName,
            WTSWinStationName,
            WTSDomainName,
            WTSConnectState,
            WTSClientBuildNumber,
            WTSClientName,
            WTSClientDirectory,
            WTSClientProductId,
            WTSClientHardwareId,
            WTSClientAddress,
            WTSClientDisplay,
            WTSClientProtocolType
        }
        public enum WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS
        {
            WTSActive,
            WTSConnected,
            WTSConnectQuery,
            WTSShadow,
            WTSDisconnected,
            WTSIdle,
            WTSListen,
            WTSReset,
            WTSDown,
            WTSInit
        }

        public static IntPtr OpenServer(String Name)
        {
            IntPtr server = WTSOpenServer(Name);
            return server;
        }
        public static void CloseServer(IntPtr ServerHandle)
        {
            WTSCloseServer(ServerHandle);
        }

        public static UserInfo GetUser(string server, string username)
        {
            return GetUsers(server).FirstOrDefault(c => c.User.Equals(username, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        }

        public static IEnumerable<UserInfo> GetUsers(String ServerName)
        {
            IntPtr serverHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            List<String> resultList = new List<string>();
            serverHandle = OpenServer(ServerName);

            try
            {
                IntPtr SessionInfoPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
                IntPtr userPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
                IntPtr domainPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
                Int32 sessionCount = 0;
                Int32 retVal = WTSEnumerateSessions(serverHandle, 0, 1, ref SessionInfoPtr, ref sessionCount);
                Int32 dataSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));
                Int32 currentSession = (int)SessionInfoPtr;
                uint bytes = 0;

                if (retVal != 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < sessionCount; i++)
                    {
                        WTS_SESSION_INFO si = (WTS_SESSION_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure((System.IntPtr)currentSession, typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));
                        currentSession += dataSize;

                        WTSQuerySessionInformation(serverHandle, si.SessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSUserName, out userPtr, out bytes);
                        WTSQuerySessionInformation(serverHandle, si.SessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSDomainName, out domainPtr, out bytes);

                        yield return new UserInfo
                        {
                            Domain = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(domainPtr),
                            User = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(userPtr),
                            SessionID = si.SessionID
                        };

                        WTSFreeMemory(userPtr);
                        WTSFreeMemory(domainPtr);
                    }

                    WTSFreeMemory(SessionInfoPtr);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseServer(serverHandle);
            }
        }
    }
    public class UserInfo
    {
        public string Domain { get; set; }
        public string User { get; set; }

        public int SessionID { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0}\\{1}: {2}", Domain, User, SessionID);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to your problem would be to use WMI to get the user information (even remotely), avoiding output redirection altogether:

```
using Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure;

string Namespace = @"root\cimv2";
string OSQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem";
CimSession mySession = CimSession.Create("Computer_B");
IEnumerable<CimInstance> queryInstance = mySession.QueryInstances(Namespace, "WQL", OSQuery);
```