# UWP: How to call WinAPI Method

Tags: javascript, windows, winapi, methods, uwp

My question is simple.
How can I call a WinAPI Method like [emptyClipboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms649037(v=vs.85).aspx) in an UWP app?

I included the 'Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP'

The method is listed under [Windows API Index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ff818516(v=vs.85).aspx) / [Data Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms632538(v=vs.85).aspx) / [Clipboard Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ff468801(v=vs.85).aspx) / [Clipboard Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ff468802(v=vs.85).aspx)

I've tried the following (`js`):

```
Windows.emptyClipboard();
Windows.WinAPI.emptyClipboard();
Windows.ApplicationModel.emptyClipboard();
Windows.DataExchange.emptyClipboard();
Windows.DataExchange.Clipboard.emptyClipboard();
```

each of them giving me the following error (as expected):

> 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'emptyClipboard'

Comment: I would highly recommend to not empty someones clipboard unknowingly.. I guess if you are going to assign it to a button that says "Empty Clipboard" it 'could' be okay though.

Comment: `desktop apps only` - mean not implemented in UWP

Comment: @RbMm But there is an API for that

Comment: @RbMm And in UWP I can include the Desktop specific API

Comment: @ChrisCruz That's the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call WinAPI functions directly from a Universal Windows application. You have to find the equivalent function in the [Windows Runtime (WinRT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/).

To clear the Clipboard, use the follwing code:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.clear();
```

---

When you edit your UWP application project and add a reference to "Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP", you do not allow the app to call WinAPI functions directly, but you enable using a part of the Windows Runtime (WinRT) that only makes sense on desktop computers.

Here is [a list of WinRT functionality that is only available when you reference "Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn706136.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thank you for your post! Why does the 'Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP' Package exist then?

Comment: @jonhue Misunderstood your question. Answer extended

Comment: Thank you! That's what I needed :-)